# Jquery manipulating slider with .eq(n) does not work properly

Tags: jquery, slider

The slide position in div changes without correlation with eq(n) value, after I press last button (which should be last slide). What I mean is:

for example n is 1, I press last button it becomes 3 and slide should be last one. but it is not

```js
$(function(){
  
  var k = 1,  //interval periods.
  rem = 0;  //remainder of the division of k value by 3
  
setInterval(function(){
  
  if (rem == 0) {           //to be able to switch picture without having to wait for slide to change  I use remainder of division by 3 for slider. So that slide change appears in every 1.5 seconds, but I have 3 periods of main interval ( 500ms) when I can interact with slider.
 n = Math.floor(k/3) // the actual value of slide from 0 to 3
    $('.slider > :first-child').appendTo('.slider').fadeOut(1000);
    $('.slider > *').eq(n).prependTo('.slider').fadeIn(1000);
 alert ("picture="+n+" K="+k);
 }
 if (k<11) {k++} //it should be 9, but to have 1.5 seconds between 3 and 0 it is 11
 else if (k>=11) {k=0};
  rem = k % 3;
 
  }, 500);


$('.last').click(function(){
  k=9;   //k=9 gives n = 3
  rem=0; //rem is 0 and slide should be shown almost instantly (in 500ms).
  });
```

```css
.slider {
  position:absolute;
  width:1152px;
  height:768px;
  left: 10px;
}

.slider img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:1152px;
  height:768px;
}


ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.slider-controller{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 840px;
  left: 10px;
}

.slider-controller li {
    display: inline;
 position: relative;
 width: 64px;
 height: 64px;
}

.pressed{
 top: 2px;
 left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="slider">
 <img src="gallery/1.jpg"/>
 <img src="gallery/2.jpg"/>
 <img src="gallery/3.jpg"/>
 <img src="gallery/4.jpg"/>
</div>

 <ul class="slider-controller">
  <li class="last"><img src="img/last.png"/></li>
 </ul>
  
  </body>
```

Comment: First of all why have you referred `jquery.js` twice?

Comment: By mistake. I added extrenal library with jquery and I couldn't find remove button after I found jquery in dropmenu

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that eq(n) is searching sub element in the last change of slider

I have appendTo and prependTo that destroys all the hierarchy of images. Even without "last button" eq increments each time by 1 and takes elements with progression since elements are moving each time

I should not use this Jquery methods.

and chose something else. But I don't know what should I use.